# Visual Studio C# Project using Microsoft.CongnitiveServices.Speech doesnt work on Raspberry pi 4 with Raspbian, can someone help me?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-cognitive-services, raspberry-pi4

some time ago I worte a Text to Speech and Speech to Text bot with Visual Studio. It works fine on my Windows PC. 
I decided to bring this software to a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian, but when I tried loading my Application this Error Popped Up:

> `Unhandled Exception:
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'MyAppName.Form1:speechRecognizer' (2) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp, Version=1.6.0.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d2e6dcccb609e663' or one of its dependencies.
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'MyAppName.Form1:speechRecognizer' (2) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp, Version=1.6.0.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d2e6dcccb609e663' or one of its dependencies.`

I'm new to Linux and don't know how to fix this!

Comment: _MyAppName.Form1_ Is this some kind of WinForms application?

Comment: Yep, its a WinForms Application and Form1 is just the Form

Comment: Thats the problem, WinForms is not supported under Linux.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a GUI app using `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech` in C# and make it running on Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian OS.

Of couse, as @Rabban said in comments, `WinForms` is only supported for Windows, even for .NET Core (a cross-platform version of .NET), you can refer to the content of `README.md` of GitHub repo [`dotnet/winforms`](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms) to know it.

So for realizing your needs, the necessary requirement is all frameworks, libraries, and runtime you want to used which must be supported for Linux on ARM CPU. Then, I researched for it, as below.

1. For `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech`, I downloaded its nuget package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech and use `7zip` to see its `runtimes` as the figure below, then I was sure it's supported for Linux on ARM64 CPU. Yes, the latest Raspbian version `Buster` supports ARM64 for Respberry Pi 4.

   [image]
2. For GUI and .NET runtime, .NET Core is the only choice for Linux on Boardcom ARM CPU for Raspberry Pi. Then, I know [`Avalonia`](https://avaloniaui.net/) is a cross platform XAML in C# for .NET Core, and according to the description of its GitHub repo, as the figure, I think it may support Raspbian and ARM CPU because of the experimental support for Android and iOS.

   [image]

   Meanwhile, there is an open issue [Avalonia on Raspbian #1072](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/1072) to discuss for it. And for compatibility, please use .NET Core 2.1 and download it from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1, as the figure below.

   [image]

Finally, the last suggestion for developing I think is to develop your app using .NET Core and Avalonia in Visual Studio and make it run on PC, and then copy the source code of the project on PC to your Respbian of Respberry Pi 4 to make it as a .NET Core project to try to re-build it to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run windows application on raspberry pi I think you should use Windows IoT core OS in Raspberry Pi 4.